# How to save the data frame from the function in .py script that runs in the docker container?

Tags: python, pandas, bash, docker, ubuntu

I am trying to understand one open-source library to modify some functions. At some point, it calculates some intermediate results (the name of the object is present in several .py scripts and I assume it's a dataframe from the df name ). (I want to check the format of these dataframes to use a different input than they do from this point on)

The whole thing is running in the Docker container.

So I tried to save the object to the folder on my computer with added lines to these .py files

```
dataframe_name.to_csv('/home/username/library_name/results/datafr/test1.csv')
```

and also tried

`dataframe_name.to_csv('//home//username//library_name//results//datafr//test1.csv')`   and the same with `\ \\`

and `dataframe_name.to_csv('/app/output/transcribe_df2.csv', index=False)`

but the code won't export CSV files.

the example of the original function is

```
def calc_transcribe(video_uri, audio_file, out_loc, fl_name, r_config, deep_path, aud_dur):
    """
    Preparing Formant freq matrix
    Args:
        audio_file: (.wav) parsed audio file; fl_name: input file name
        out_loc: (str) Output directory; r_config: raw variable config
    """

text = n_util.process_deepspeech(audio_file, deep_path)
df_formant = pd.DataFrame([text], columns=[r_config.nlp_transcribe])
#mine line 
#df_formant.to_csv('/app/output/formant.csv')
df_formant.to_csv('/app/output/myformant.csv', index=False)
#mine above 
df_formant.replace('', np.nan, regex=True,inplace=True)
df_formant[r_config.nlp_totalTime] = aud_dur
df_formant[r_config.err_reason] = 'Pass'# will replace with threshold in future release
df_formant['dbm_master_url'] = video_uri

logger.info('Saving Output file {} '.format(out_loc))
ut.save_output(df_formant, out_loc, fl_name, formant_dir, csv_ext)
```

in the initial sh script there are lines that start the container and specify output path id that the actual place where the container is?

```
docker create -ti --name dbm_container dbm bash docker cp $input_path dbm_container:/app/raw_data docker start dbm_container

if [ -z "$dbm_new" ]

then

docker exec -it dbm_container /bin/bash -c "python3 -W ignore

process_data.py --input_path /app/raw_data --output_path /app/output"

else

docker exec -it dbm_container /bin/bash -c "python3 -W ignore

process_data.py --input_path /app/raw_data --output_path /app/output --

dbm_group$dbm_new"

fi

docker cp dbm_container:/app/output $output_path

docker stop dbm_container docker rm dbm_container
```

how I can save these mid calculation results to any accessible folder to check what it takes in? How to save the data frame from the function in .py script that runs in the docker container?

Comment: You might find a [Python virtual environment](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/installing-packages/#creating-virtual-environments) to be a better match for what you're trying.  This has an isolated set of Python packages, and will let you develop your forked library, but still uses the normal host filesystem and doesn't require low-level debug commands like `docker exec` or `docker cp`.

Comment: Thank you so much! I just wasn't able to install everything without docker. I guess I should try again